# Passing Arguments Through Higher Order Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, arguments, higher-order-functions

Im using React and I want to pass a few arguments in addition to the 'event', so I decided to use Higher Order function for this.

However, it doesn't recognise the 'id' which was passed to the Higher Order function.

**container component**

```
...
const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
    return({
        dispatchSelectElement : function( e ){
            console.log( id ); // Error: id is not defined.
            dispatch( selectElement( id, type, pos ));
        },
        ...
    });
};
const C_ElementParent = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( ElementParent );
```

There is another component that sits between the container component & the presentation component below. The props are being passed fine, as reported by console.log. The `dispatchSelectElement` above is passed inside `eventProps` below.

**presentational component**

```
const Element = ({ id, colorName, eleProps, eventProps }) => {
    let handleDispatchSelectEle = function( id ){
        return eventProps.dispatchSelectElement;
    }
    return(
        <g id = { id }>
            <path onMouseDown = { eleProps.get( "mouseDown" ) && handleDispatchSelectEle( id )} />
        </g>
    );
};
```

Comment: Where are you passing an id to which function? In the code you've shown us, there's indeed no `id` variable in scope at the point where the error occurs. Why did you think it should be defined there?

Comment: @Bergi the `id` is passed in handleDispatchSelectEle function within the `path` element. Then handleDispatchSelectEle returns the dispatchSelectElement function.

Comment: Uh, I see now. That's not how it works. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope is lexical, which means that `id` would be only available inside the body of your `handleDispatchSelectEle` function (where it is not used). That the function returns `eventProps.dispatchSelectElement` doesn't matter, that's a distinct function with its own scope.

You will need to write

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        handleDispatchSelectElement: (id) => (e) => {
//                                    ^ from here on, `id` is in scope
            console.log( id ); // Error: id is not defined.
            dispatch( selectElement( id, type, pos ));
        },
        …
    };
}
```

```
function Element({ id, colorName, eleProps, eventProps }) {
    // pass the id here, to create a function:
    const dispatchSelectEle = eventProps.handleDispatchSelectElement(id);
    return (
        <g id={id}>
            <path onMouseDown={ eleProps.get("mouseDown") && dispatchSelectEle } />
        </g>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I understood lexical scope, clearly not! Its back to revision.